# Output argument in dynamics custom workflow will not show up in process designer

Tags: c#, workflow, microsoft-dynamics

I just started as CRM developer at a college. We use Ellucian, which is CRM for higher ed built on MS Dynamics. Trying to test custom workflows. Code clearly has output argument. just a string for testing:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WheatonPluginDelta.Activities
{
    public class AppointmentPopulateSpouse1 : CodeActivity
    {
        [RequiredArgument]
        [Input("Person")]
        [ReferenceTarget("contact")]
         public InArgument<EntityReference> PersonRef { get; set; }

        [RequiredArgument]
        [Input("Appointment")]
        [ReferenceTarget("appointment")]
        public InArgument<EntityReference> AppointmentRef { get; set; }

        [Output("output string")]
        public OutArgument<string> MyOutput { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {
            ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
            IWorkflowContext workflowContext = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            IOrganizationService orgService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(workflowContext.UserId);



            EntityReference personRef = PersonRef.Get(executionContext);
            EntityReference appointmentRef = AppointmentRef.Get(executionContext);

            var appointment = new Entity("appointment", appointmentRef.Id);

            var spouse = orgService.Retrieve("contact", personRef.Id, new ColumnSet("spousesname"));

            if (spouse["spousesname"] != null)
            {
                MyOutput.Set(executionContext, spouse["spousesname"]);
            }
            else
            {
                MyOutput.Set(executionContext, "no spouse found");
            }
        }
    }
```

After registering, input arguments do show up on designer, but output arguments don't when I call the custom workflow on the second step:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXBcT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReZWo.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to remove space from the "output string"?

Answer (score 0):

Put the focus on one of the "string" fields and try that again.